# how to route www.domain.com to httpswww.domain.com in Route 53?

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, elastic-load-balancer

We are trying to route www.example.com to https://www.example.com using route 53 when ever user search for www.example.com

We redirected all the traffic from example.com to https://www.example.com by using S3 bucket Redirect all request, then assigned alias target as example.com bucket in route53.

Now the challange we are unable to do the same on www.example.com wherin loadbalancer DNS is linked with www.example.com as alias target in Route53. So how do i can route the traffic from www.example.com to https://www.example.com

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use an S3 static website, and want to force https redirects, then you also need to use cloudfront in front of the s3 website to make it all work.

https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2016/08/redirect-domain-https-amazon-cloudfront/